# Angular 2 - Firebase - Is there a way to search the entire Firebase auth accounts for one that matches an email?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if there's a way to be able to see if an email exists inside of the Firebase auth for all of the accounts that exist when users sign up. Is there a way to use `AngularFireAuth` inside of an Angular 2 service?

I have my authentication all setup but now I'm trying to create some functionality to invite a user to a project that's created within the Firebase database, and I want to check an `invites` tree table upon user login.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client side library you can call:
`firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail('user@example.com').then(function(providers) {
  console.log(providers);
})`
If providers is not empty then the account exists.

Using the admin node.js library, you can use:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail('user@example.com').then(function(userRecord) {});
```

Comment: Hey thankyou for the response! I tried the fetchProvidersForEmail() function like you suggested and the response comes back like `["password"]` if the account exists. If I wanted the data related to that account for that email, such as the `uid, would I need to use the admin node.js library like you mentioned? And if so, is that built into Firebase or is there a separate npm module I need to install? Thanks!

Comment: The client side API will not return account specific reason and it should not as it could reveal sensitive data. If you want that data, you are better off using the admin SDK. It is a separate npm module: firebase-admin

Comment: Awesome, thanks @bojeil, I'll check it out. It looks like it'll do what I need it to :)